# Can't find the location of DUMPed file system

Tags: filesystems, find, locate, restore, dump

I dumped a file system, chose the name for the dump ("`home_fs_dump`"), the dump was declared successfull, and yet I couldn't `locate` this name anywhere in the system. (And at the end I tested if `locate` gives me any files at all, or if I am using it incorrectly.)

Is a dump locateable by other command than `locate`? If yes, then what?
Or did I make a mistake of some other sort somewhere?

(I need to know this to `restore` the dump.)

```
[root@12345 /]# dump -0uf home_fs_dump /dev/mapper/fedora_12345-home
  DUMP: Date of this level 0 dump: Sat Apr 25 21:08:02 2015
  DUMP: Dumping /dev/mapper/fedora_12345-home (/home) to home_fs_dump
  DUMP: Label: none
  DUMP: Writing 10 Kilobyte records
  DUMP: mapping (Pass I) [regular files]
  DUMP: mapping (Pass II) [directories]
  DUMP: estimated 22551 blocks.
  DUMP: Volume 1 started with block 1 at: Sat Apr 25 21:08:02 2015
  DUMP: dumping (Pass III) [directories]
  DUMP: dumping (Pass IV) [regular files]
  DUMP: Closing home_fs_dump
  DUMP: Volume 1 completed at: Sat Apr 25 21:08:04 2015
  DUMP: Volume 1 23010 blocks (22.47MB)
  DUMP: Volume 1 took 0:00:02
  DUMP: Volume 1 transfer rate: 11505 kB/s
  DUMP: 23010 blocks (22.47MB) on 1 volume(s)
  DUMP: finished in 2 seconds, throughput 11505 kBytes/sec
  DUMP: Date of this level 0 dump: Sat Apr 25 21:08:02 2015
  DUMP: Date this dump completed:  Sat Apr 25 21:08:04 2015
  DUMP: Average transfer rate: 11505 kB/s
  DUMP: DUMP IS DONE
[root@12345 /]# locate home_fs_*
[root@12345 /]# locate *fs_dump
[root@12345 /]# locate *_fs_*
[root@12345 /]# locate home_*
[root@12345 /]# locate home*
/home
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.homedirs
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.homedirs.bin
/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/file_contexts.homedirs
/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/homedir_template
/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/tmp/file_contexts.homedirs
/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/tmp/homedir_template
(...)
```

Comment: Have you tried find? find ./ -name "*home_fs_dump*"

Comment: I am glad to hear that. The reason "locate" could not find this file is because, locate keeps a cache/index of all files in the system. But it relies on cron to trigger this at a specified frequency. Find  on the other hand checks the directory entries to search for files/dirs.

Comment: @SoumyadipDM make it an answer.

Comment: locate database can be updated with an `updatedb` (as root) command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making it an answer as suggested

```
find / -name "home_f_dump"
```